# How to force the pointer to the next row of the same column in a csv file using php?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm trying to write some data to the csv file and downloading it when the php file is run. I wanted to write an array in csv, and that array itself contains another array. I want to write it in the next row of the csv. I have done the following code.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/utf-8');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="testexport.csv"'); 
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$i = 1;
$lines = array(1,2);
$columns = array();
$alphabets = array(array('a','b','b'),array('c','d','c'),array('d','e','d'));
//this array may contain any number of array, for simplicity I have defined here
foreach ($lines as $line) {
$columns['first'] = '1';
$columns['second'] = '2';
$columns['third'] = '3';

foreach ($alphabets as $alphabet) {
   $columns['fourth'] = $alphabet[0];
   $columns['fifth'] = $alphabet[1];
}

$columns['sixth'] = '6';
$columns['seventh'] = '7';

if($i == 1) fputcsv($fp, array_keys($columns));
fputcsv($fp, $columns);
$i++;
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

My downloaded csv file currently looks like this

```
first   second  third   fourth  fifth   sixth   seventh
  1       2       3        d       e       6       7
  1       2       3        d       e       6       7
```

But I want the output like this.

```
first   second  third   fourth  fifth   sixth   seventh
  1        2      3        a      b       6         7
                           c      d
                           d      e
  1        2      3        a      b       6         7
                           c      d
                           d      e
```

I'm able understand that I'm certainly doing wrong, But I don't know how to solve it.

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this loop is just over-writing the same variables multiple times; you are not doing anything with `$colums` [sic] on each loop, so no extra rows are being written to the file.

```
foreach ($alphabets as $alphabet) {
    $colums['fourth'] = $alphabet[0];
    $colums['fifth'] = $alphabet[1];
}
```

Secondly, `fputcsv` does not take any account of array keys, just the position of data in the array. So in order to align data to a particular column, you must specify empty values for the columns leading up to that.

So, you need to rearrange your loops so that you're writing a whole row for every alphabet, but leaving blanks on everything except the first. Perhaps something like this:

```
// Add header:
fputcsv($fp, array(
    'first',
    'second',
    'third',
    'fourth',
    'fifth',
    'sixth',
    'seventh'
));

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $first_alphabet = true;

    foreach ($alphabets as $alphabet) { 
        if ( $first_alphabet ) {
            // Full line
            fputcsv($fp, array(
                '1',
                '2',
                '3',
                $alphabet[0],
                $alphabet[1],
                '6',
                '7'
            ));
            $first_alphabet = false;
        } else {
            // Partial line
            fputcsv($fp, array(
                '',
                '',
                '',
                $alphabet[0],
                $alphabet[1],
                '',
                ''
            ));
        }
    }
}
```